# Logout from Ubuntu One Android app

Tags: ubuntu-one, android, files, logout

How can I logout from the Ubuntu One Files apps on Android ?
Is it possible to have a login screen everytime I star the application ?
If I lose my phone, someone can just upload or download from my account because the Ubuntu One app seems like always logged in. Is there any way to logout ??
Thanks.
Andy.

Answer (score 1):

You can not 'log out' technically but you can force your system to request your ID every time you open the application.

You need to do the following (Its a bit long winded!)

1.Open settings
2. Click advanced options
3. Remove device from U1

Now you have logged out however your device is still logged in to your OpenID

To solve this open the app again and you will be taken to the grant access screen where you can completely log out at the top of the screen.
This way whenever your open the app you will need to log in again.

Answer (score 0):

Try deauthorizing the device from ubuntu one control panel in Ubuntu